# Good naming convention for getter

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

If I have a variable called `value` and if I want to write its getter, 
will `getvalue()` be a good name for the getter. Or is `getValue()` is better?

Someone told me that the getter name should match the variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per section 8.3 Design Patterns for Properties from the [JavaBean spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) your getter should be called `getValue` or `isValue` (if it is a `boolean`)

Answer (score 3):

If your value is boolean then it should be "isValue", if not then "getValue" (according to JavaBean convention).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) all methods should be named using Camel Case. So `getValue()` would be the proper name.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one "good" naming convention for getters, the JavaBean convention:

```
public TheType getValue() { return value; }
```

Booleans may follow the `is` convention (its setter should be `setValue`):

```
public boolean isValue() { return value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick with `getValue()` standard - it is called [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have two variables, named `value` and `Value`, the convention stands with `getValue()` (or `isValue()`, if `value` is of type `boolean`).

Comment: and having a variable named `Value` (uppercase) is against the coding guidelines, too. One would expect that to be the name of a class.